# Why is it valid to not fully expand the inequality in the convergence in probability definition?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be iid random variables with common pdf
$$f(x) = e^{−(x−\theta)}\quad,  x > \theta ,\, − \infty < \theta < \infty\,;
\quad 0 \quad\text{elsewhere}$$

Let $Y_n = \min({X_1,\ldots,X_n})$. Prove
that $Y_n\to\theta$ in probability, by first obtaining the cdf of $Y_n$.

By definition, we want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $P[|Y_n-\theta|\le\epsilon]=1$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P[-\epsilon<Y_n-\theta\le\epsilon]=\lim_{n\to\infty}P[-\epsilon+\theta<Y_n\le\epsilon+\theta]\tag{1}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P[Y_n-\theta\le\epsilon]=\lim_{n\to\infty}P[Y_n\le\epsilon+\theta]\tag{2}$$

I know that $(2)$ helps me prove this, but why is it ok to skip $(1)$ ?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of $f$ it is clear that $X_i \geq \theta$ for each $i$. Hence $Y_n \geq \theta $. Now $P(|Y_n-\theta| \geq \epsilon)= P(Y_n \geq \theta+\epsilon)=(P(X_1 \geq \theta+\epsilon))^{n}=(1-e^{-\epsilon})^{n} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$.

The reason you can skip $Y_n \leq \theta -\epsilon$ is $Y_n \geq \theta $ almost surely.

Comment: Thank you, it does clarify a lot. What about in the case the probability that it less than epsilon? Then, would it be  lim n->infinity P(theta-epsilon<Y_n<theta+epsilon). Since Y_n>theta, Would I have  to find lim n->infinity P(Y_n>theta-epsilon)?

Comment: You have to show that probability of  $|Y_n-\theta |>\epsilon$ tends to $0$. [This is the definition of convergence in probability]. This event is made of two disjoint events: $Y_n > \theta +\epsilon$ and $Y_n < \theta -\epsilon$. In this case the second event has probability $0$ because $Y_n \geq \theta$. Hence the only thing you have to show is that probability of $Y_n > \theta +\epsilon$  tends to $0$.